# Import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors

Tags: go, grpc

I have a proto file where I want to add pagination. The technology stack is GoLang with gRPC.

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

When try to add the dependency via `go install` or `go get`. I get

```
go install protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto@latest                                                       
go: protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto@latest: malformed module path "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto": missing dot in first path element
```

---

```
go get protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto                                                                  
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
```

When I read the [documentation](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/development/grpc-gateway_v2_migration_guide/) it appears I am doing this correctly. Has anyone else had this issue?

```
message BlogAllRequest {
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_schema) = {
        json_schema: {
            required: ["filter"]
        }
    };

    string id = 1;
    int32 page = 2;
    int32 per_page = 3 [json_name="per_page"];
    SortOrder order = 4 [json_name = "order"];

}
```

Comment: The error says “go.mod file not found”, you didn’t create a module yet.

Comment: @JimB yes I did...

Comment: You must have a go.mod file to have a module. That error is what you will get when working outside of a module.

Comment: Directly from the error you pasted: "go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** Apologies I'm less familiar with gRPC Gateway but I'm very familiar with Protocol Buffers (and gRPC). So, I can't help with the full solution but I can show you how to compile your proto.

With Protocol Buffers you need source files locally (e.g. `.proto` files). You **cannot** `go get` nor `go install` Protocol Buffer files.

The `grpc-gateway` protos that you need are:

- [`annotations.proto`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/main/protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto)
- [`openapiv2.proto`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/main/protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/openapiv2.proto)

For the next step, it's probably easiest to `git clone` the [`grpc-gateway`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) repo. The protos mentioned above are in the repo's `./protoc-gen-openapiv2` folder.

I've cloned it into my working directory (see tree below).

The first step is to then `protoc` compile your proto referencing these protos. Here's my completion of your proto file:

`foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "{MODULE}/protos";

import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto";

message BlogAllRequest {
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_schema) = {
        json_schema: {
            required: ["filter"]
        }
    };

    enum SortOrder{
        BAR = 0;
        BAZ = 1;
    }

    string id = 1;
    int32 page = 2;
    int32 per_page = 3 [json_name="per_page"];
    SortOrder order = 4 [json_name = "order"];
}
```

**NOTE** Replace `{MODULE}` with your repo name. Generally your repo name will match your Go module name. As I've done, you may want to add e.g. `/protos` to your `{MODULE}` value for the value of `go_package` as this provides the protoc-generated sources with their own package name. I also add an arbitrary `SortOrder` type.

You can now `protoc` compile your proto:

```bash
# Your go.mod module value and probably matching your Git repo 
MODULE="..."

# Doing this here to prove the point
go mod init ${MODULE}

# Protoc will output foo.pb.go in protos folder
# This will make it the ${MODULE}/protos package
mkdir protos

protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--proto_path=${PWD}/grpc-gateway \
--go_out=./protos \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PWD}/foo.proto
```

`protoc` is **very** particularly about paths. I always root it on my working directory (`${PWD}`) and, in this case, I've cloned `gprc-gateway` into the working directory. Both folders contain protos and so both must be `proto_path`'d. Because I used `${PWD}` for the `proto_path`, I must prefix proto filenames with `${PWD}` too (i.e. `${PWD}/foo.proto`). It's `protoc`'s way.

Importantly, I want your proto compiled into a package ending `protos` and so I need to reflect this in the working folder too

To ensure `protoc` knows that my working directory (with `go.mod`) is my Go module root, you can use `--go_opt=module=${MODULE}` to place the files correctly.

I've called your partial proto `foo.proto`.

The `grpc-gateway` repo not only includes the `protos` (`./protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/*.proto`) but it also includes the protoc-generated Golang sources (`./protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/*.pb.go`). This is a (helpful) choice (I think, good practice) made by the repo maintainers and it means that you don't need to generate these sources for yourself.

In fact, your protoc-generated `foo.pb.go` should include the correct references to these sources and you will just need to `go mod tidy` to `go get` them. Here's the beginning of the `foo.pb.go` that I generated:

`foo.pb.go`:

```golang
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//  protoc-gen-go v1.28.1
//  protoc        v3.21.12
// source: foo.proto

package protos

import (
    _ "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2/options"
    protoreflect "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    protoimpl "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
    reflect "reflect"
    sync "sync"
)
```

Running `tree`:

```bash
tree
.
├── foo.proto
├── go.mod
├── grpc-gateway
│   ├── protoc-gen-openapiv2
│   │   └── options
│   │       ├── annotations.pb.go
│   │       ├── annotations.proto
│   │       ├── annotations.swagger.json
│   │       ├── BUILD.bazel
│   │       ├── openapiv2.pb.go
│   │       ├── openapiv2.proto
│   │       └── openapiv2.swagger.json
├── protoc-21.12-linux-x86_64
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── protoc
│   ├── include
│   │   └── google
│   │       └── protobuf
│   │           ├── any.proto
│   │           ├── api.proto
│   │           ├── compiler
│   │           │   └── plugin.proto
│   │           ├── descriptor.proto
│   │           ├── duration.proto
│   │           ├── empty.proto
│   │           ├── field_mask.proto
│   │           ├── source_context.proto
│   │           ├── struct.proto
│   │           ├── timestamp.proto
│   │           ├── type.proto
│   │           └── wrappers.proto
│   └── readme.txt
└── protos
    └── protos
        └── foo.pb.go
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed response. The answer was I needed the repo you suggested. I have a working proto command and was generating files with it. It was when I added. protoc-gen-openapiv2 it stopped working and I was not able to add the dependency.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pleased that it helped.